# Optimize S3 download for large number of tiny files

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, io

I currently use [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) to download all files in an S3 bucket, from a Lambda function.

```
// Initialize
TransferManagerBuilder txBuilder = TransferManagerBuilder.standard();
// txBuilder.setExecutorFactory(() -> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50));
TransferManager tx = txBuilder.build();
final Path tmpDir = Files.createTempDirectory("/tmp/s3_download/");

// Download
MultipleFileDownload download = tx.downloadDirectory(bucketName,
                                                     bucketKey,
                                                     new File(tmpDir.toUri()));
download.waitForCompletion();

return Files.list(tmpDir.resolve(bucketKey)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It seems to take around `300 seconds` to download `10,000 files` (of size `~20KB each`), giving me a transfer rate of about `666 KBps`.
Increasing the thread pool size doesn't seem to affect the transfer rate at all.

The S3 endpoint, and the lambda function are in the same AWS region, and in the same AWS account.

How can I optimize the S3 downloads?

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with a large number of data always needs architecting your storage with regards to underlying systems.

If you need high throughputs you need to partition your s3 keys so that it can accommodate a high number of requests. Distributed computing comes with own needs to serve with high performance, this is one such need.

**Request Rate Considerations:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

**Transfer Acceleration:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

**How to Improve throughput:**

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-performance-improve/

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1**

I see that you are trying to download files to Ephemeral storage, you need to be aware of storage limits. Those are not meant for bulk processing.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: My files do have a hashed prefix attached. I am looking for solutions that help me achieve solutions closer to 300 reqs per second (the current TransferManager gives me around 33 files per second).

CloudFront doesn't work for me either because of my workload.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Lambda limitations. I am aware of the Ephemeral storage, and I'm trying to process files which are well within these limits (10,000 files of size ~20KB each ~=200MB < 512MB). I am also aware of the file descriptor limit of 1024 - are you suggesting that this is the bottleneck for download speeds in my particular case?

Comment: That is too much to handle in Lambda storage. You need to use external storage for scalability.