# S3DistCp from a Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a use-case where I need to download, and process, a large number (order of 10<sup>4</sup>) of tiny files (file size 30KB each) from an S3 bucket.

Because downloading all these files locally seems to give a very low throughput, I am evaluating ways to fetch the "aggregated" files from S3.

Can I use [s3-dist-cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) from a Lambda function to do that? Is there any other way I can aggregate these files before my download?

Comment: s3distcp runs on Hadoop (and EMR). It won't run in Lambda, though you could use Lambda to launch an EMR cluster and run s3distcp on that cluster to aggregate the files. Or you could just try running the awscli (aws s3 sync) on an EC2 instance and see if it's usable.

Answer (score 2):

You could call out to the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) that has an `aws s3 sync` command. It copies files in parallel and would be simpler than writing your own.

See: [Running aws-cli Commands Inside An AWS Lambda Function - Alestic.com](https://alestic.com/2016/11/aws-lambda-awscli/)

Comment: Would `s3 sync` give a better speed than TransferManager.downloadDirectory? I have been using TransferManager in the lambda with a very low throughput ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903019/optimize-s3-download-for-large-number-of-tiny-files)).

Comment: Most probably. I suggest you test it and find out!